# How to overload the fdiff method of a personal function inheriting from the Function class?

Tags: python, function, sympy, derivative

I would like to create a polynomial function P(n,x,y) whose derivative is equal to n/x*E(n,x,y). I've created the function like this :

```
from sympy.core.function import Function as Func, ArgumentIndexError

class P(Func) :        
    @classmethod     
    def eval(cls,n,x,y):        
        return Function('P')(n,x,y)  

class E(Func):    
    @classmethod     
    def eval(cls,n,x,y):        
        return Function('E')(n,x,y)
```

I have put:

```
def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
    if argindex == 1:
        return self.args[2]/self.args[0]*E(*self.args)        
    else:
        raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)
```

right after the "eval" definition of the function P, as it is done for example in the trigonometric.py to define the derivative of cos thanks to sin.

Yet, when I try:

```
>>> P(r, R, n).fdiff()
```

I obtain:

```
Derivative(P(n,x,y), n)
```

in the console, whereas I would like to obtain n/x*E(n,x,y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eval` is returning `Function('P')`, which is a completely different object (an anonymous function named "P"). `eval` should be used to evaluate specific values (like numbers). If you don't have any values to evaluate at, don't define `eval`.

When I define `P` and `E` like

```
class P(Function):
    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return self.args[2]/self.args[0]*E(*self.args)
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)


class E(Function):
    pass
```

it works just fine

```
In [32]: P(r, R, n).diff(r)
Out[32]:
n⋅E(r, R, n)
────────────
     r
```